# Line breaks in \hyperlink text

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, line-breaking, hyperlink, hypertarget

I'm writing a document with lots of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` in them using `pdflatex`.

I'm trying to get the text of

```
\hyperlink{label}{very long text that should line break}
```

to line break. Similarly with

```
\hyperref[label]{very long text that should line break}
```

I'm including `hyperref` with

```
\usepackage[linktocpage,
            ocgcolorlinks,
            allcolors=blue,
            breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

unfortunately to no avail. How can I get the link text to line break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hyperref`'s `ocgcolorlinks` option prevents line breaking inside the link text.

Use package **`ocgx2`** instead. It allows longer link text to wrap around **line** and **page breaks**:

```
\usepackage[linktocpage,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
```